# How to implement button next to navigation bar title

Tags: ios, swift

When you create a new shortcut in the iOS Shortcuts app, you will see that there is a three dots button next to the navigation bar title:
[navigation title button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDopL.jpg)

That button will follow the position from the navigation title if you scroll up or scroll down in the view.

I would like to implement that button using as little code as possible and following the iOS 13 standards. What is the best way to implement it?